# How to apply the "hover" effect with css

Tags: css, image, button, hover, effect

I've got a doubt with the css hover effect applied to a background image that have buttons designed. The purpose is to call other images with the same size of the size of the buttons.

It works but the image that is called by the "hover" property occupies the all screen.

Thanks

```css
<head>
  <style scoped="scoped" type="text/css">
    .menu-map {
      width:100%; 
      position:relative; 
      margin-bottom:20px;
    } 
    
    .menu-map img {
      display:block; 
      width:100%;
    } 
    
    .menu-map .hotspots {
      width:100%; 
      height:100%; 
      position:absolute; 
      left:0; 
      top:0; 
      visibility:hidden;
    }
   
    .menu-map a {
      display:block; 
      position:absolute; 
      background:#000; 
      z-index:100; 
      opacity:0; 
      filter: alpha(opacity=0); 
      border:0px solid transparent; 
      border-radius:20px;
    }

    .menu-map a.p1 {
      left:26%;
      top:26%; 
      width:10%; 
      height:20%;
    } /* ACES */

    .menu-map:hover .hotspots {
      visibility:visible;
    } 

    .menu-map .hotspots div:hover b {
      width:0; 
      padding:0;
    }

    .menu .hotspots div:hover p {
      display:block;
    } 

    #BUTTON1 img.p1:hover {
      opacity:0;
      left:26%; 
      top:26%; 
      width:10%; 
      height:20%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div>
<div class="menu-map"><img src="images/image_with_menu_buttons.png" alt="Navigation Menu" /> 
   <div class="hotspots">
   <div title="BUTTON1"><img class="p1" aria-haspopup="false" href="page1" target="_self" rel="nofollow" src="images/button1_to_hover_effect.png" ></a></div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So the problem isn't applying the hover effect, but instead sizing the image? Have you tried `width` and `height`?

Comment: Thanks for answering but I've already put that information in the button properties or isn't right?

Comment: Thanks Ghost but still doesn't work :( can you give me an hand please?

Comment: I didn't actually post an answer yet, just edited things to be a little more readable. To be honest, you'll need to post a working example of the page in order to research further. Post it on jsfiddle. As @IlpoOksanen mentioned, it's most likely that the images need to have `width` and `height` added directly.